# - Update a UISegmentedControl of a UITabBarItem -

Tags: iphone

I found out that I couldn't do it but just to make sure, would it be possible to disable one of the button of my segmentedcontrol without re-creating the whole thing ?

Exemple:

> [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.accessToMySegmentedControl
>   setEnabled:NO ...];

Cheers mates,

Gauthier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a reference to the segmented control in your controller like this:

Foo.h

```
@interface Foo : UIViewController {
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
}
```

Foo.m

```
segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items];
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

UIBarButtonItem *bar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:bar];
[bar release];
```

Then you can always use `segmentedControl` to access your segmented control.

Comment: Well done ;)

Really easy but I wouldn't have thought about it :D

Thanks.